# Weblogic Server getting SAXParse Exception

Tags: java, weblogic12c, saxparser

Using Weblogic 12.1.2 I am trying to use the below code while parsing XSL I am getting the below error,

```
  TransformerFactory tFactory = new TransformerFactoryImpl();
  Source xslSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(myXslfile);
  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslSource);
  StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlFile);
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  transformer.transform(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(reader),
                new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));
```

Exception

```
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 12; 
columnNumber: 58;
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:418)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:214)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:50)
at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1611)
```

This same piece of code is working fine if I run seperately but once it is deployed as war in Weblogic server it is not working and throwing this exception. Please suggest is there any way to resolve this issue

Comment: This usually happens when you have characters before the xml declaration (<?xml ...). please remove any character or line or space before (<?xml ...) in xsl file.

Comment: Yes error related to xml and might be xml file which used in deployment of your war/ear @AnuragDadheech: In this case the error like `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; 
columnNumber: 1;`

Comment: But the same xml is working in standalone jar but not in deployed in WLS it is throwing this error